# Adding a result of a calculation to a span with JavaScript after a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm new to JavaScript and I would like you to help me figure out why I can't get the result of the random number generator to appear in the span tag after the user clicks a calculate button using the min and max number they entered. I believe there is nothing wrong with the random number function it's just when I want to use the random number function as an event handler for the `onclick` event for the button it doesn't work. well, what I did was, I made a function called answer to gather the users input and to use that input as a parameter for the the random number function that is being called inside the answer function.

Then I used the answer function as an event handler for the `onclick` thinking that it would have the result of the the random number generator and would apply that to the `onclick` and I stored that in var called `storage` so I could place the result of the event in the span tag later.

Here is the js fiddle of the code. Can you help me solve my problem by getting the result of the random_number function in to the span `$("output")` after the button `$("calculate")` click?

Only pure JavaScript, no jQuery please.

I'm sorry if I got terminology wrong and for bad spelling. http://jsfiddle.net/jack2ky/WDyMd/

```
<label for="min">Enter the min:</label>
<input type="text" id = "min" /> <br />

<label for="max">Enter the max:</label>
<input type="text" id = "max" /> <br />

<input type="button" id = "calculate" value = "calculate"/>
<span id ="output">&nbsp;</span>
<script>

var $ = function(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
window.onload = function () {


    var random_number = function(min, max, digits){
        digits = isNaN(digits) ? 0 : parseInt(digits);

        if(digits < 0){
            digits = 0;
        }else if (digits > 16){
            digits = 16
        }
        if(digits == 0){
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min +1)) +min;
        }else {
            var rand = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
            return parseFloat(rand.toFixed(digits));
        }
    }

    
    var storage = $("calculate").onclick = answer;

     var answer = function(){
            var miny = $("min").value;
            var maxy = $("max").value;
            return random_number(miny, maxy);
     }
    $("output").firstChild.nodeValue = storage;

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var storage = $("calculate").onclick = answer;
...
$("output").firstChild.nodeValue = storage;
```

These two statements are called on page load. What is happening is you are changing the value of variable `storage` but the statement `var storage = $("calculate").onclick = answer;`
 is being called only once when the page loads. You need to update the answer when user clicks the button. So you can remove `$("output").firstChild.nodeValue = storage;` and update the answer function like:

```
 var answer = function(){               
                var miny = parseInt( $("min").value );              
                var maxy = parseInt( $("max").value );                      
                var ans = random_number(miny, maxy);                
                $("output").innerHTML = ans;
         }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. it works :) I get confused over this window.onload object property thing. some times I'm able to call things in the window.onload function and it works and other times it doesn't. This is one thing that I hope to fix in my progress with learning js. I think I understand what you did though. But about the parseInt I thought a good example of using parseInt is when a user puts in a number with decimals like 198.345 it would cut it off to 198. why in this case does it make a difference for the result by outputing 111 when a user puts 1-10max leaving out parseInt.

Comment: Glad to know that it worked :). The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer. This is required in this case because you are getting min and max value from textbox which is evaluated as numeric string by default. So if `min = 5; max = 10` the output of expressions like `min + max` will be `510` instead of `15`. You can use `parseFloat()` to parse floating point numbers. Yes you can also use `parseInt()` to cutoff number with decimal but its not the actual use of it.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
            var $ = function(id){
                return document.getElementById(id);
            }
            window.onload = function () {
                var random_number = function(min, max, digits){
                    digits = isNaN(digits) ? 0 : parseInt(digits);

                    if(digits < 0){
                        digits = 0;
                    }else if (digits > 16){
                        digits = 16
                    }
                    if(digits == 0){
                        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min +1)) +min;
                    }else {
                        var rand = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
                        return parseFloat(rand.toFixed(digits));
                    }
                }
                $("calculate").onclick = function() {
                    var miny = $("min").value;
                    var maxy = $("max").value;
                    $("output").firstChild.nodeValue = random_number(miny, maxy);
                }
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
       <label for="min">Enter the min:</label>
    <input type="text" id = "min" /> <br />

    <label for="max">Enter the max:</label>
    <input type="text" id = "max" /> <br />

    <input type="button" id = "calculate" value = "calculate"/>
    <span id ="output">&nbsp;</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> $("output").firstChild.nodeValue = storage;

This line seems to be the problem because your output-Element has no firstChild. So the value gets written nowhere.

Just use

```
> $("output").nodeValue = storage;
```

edit: Tested this in jsFiddle - this is not the solutions as mentioned below!

Comment: Thanks for your response but it doesn't seem to work. when the user enters a min and max the random number within that range should appear below in the span tag after the click. tried getting rid of .firstChild but it still doesn't work.

Comment: At the moment I dont have the time to test any further - but i'll look again when i'm home and test it if nobody else responds.

Answer (score 0):

If You are able to get your value in the variable storage

then you can simply render this value in span as HTML

```
$("#output span").html = storage;
```

Comment: The op asked for pure javascript; no jquery.